# calling a custom function for groupHeaderTpl- extJS

Tags: extjs

I am using a custom function which I am calling under a column like this to change the format. I have defined the function which works well.

```
renderer: function(v, params, record,row){
            return readableDuration(v) + ' Hrs';
        }
```

Now I want to use the same under `groupHeaderTpl` by passing an argument. But I am not able to get it. Could you help? Here is my code for `groupHeaderTpl`

```
groupHeaderTpl:[
                    '{name} {[readableDuration({[values.rows[0].data.tbp]})]}'

           ]
```

where `tbp` is a parameter I read from respective json data

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```js
groupHeaderTpl: Ext.create( 'Ext.XTemplate', '{name} {tbp:this.readableDuration}',
    {
        readableDuration : function( v ) {
            return readableDuration( v ) + ' Hrs';
        }
    }
)
```